# npm cannot install 'node-sass'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, sass, npm-install

I'm trying to run a project with npm start and then get the following error in a bunch of different components:

```
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
```

Alright, I'm thinking and I run 'npm install node-sass', which then leaves me with the following error:

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, open '/usr/app/client/node_modules/node-sass/package.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:670:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/app/client/node_modules/node-sass/lib/extensions.js:7:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
```

I don't know what it means or what I can do to resolve it, I tried commands like npm rebuild, npm uninstall and then install again, deleted the node_modules folder but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: use nvm to install node version & try 'npm install' with different node version

Comment: I had that problem before I solved it by installing the latest version of node and npm.

Comment: @EduardoVargas I'm running the most recent versions of both (npm 6.4.1, node vv8.12.0) and I still have this issue

Comment: Try instaling version 10+ of node

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this would work.
    The package.json I have was written like the following.

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    ...
  }

npm install node-sass
npm install node-sass@latest
npm rebuild node-sass --force
npm install node-sass --force
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so the solution to my specific problem was:

```
npm install node-sass --force
```

and then I had to do

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

And then I got it to compile

Answer (score 1):

Try running :

```
npm install node-sass --force
```

It would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

in Linux:

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Answer (score 0):

None of those options worked for me. I was trying to install node-sass version 4.14.1 and this seemed to work:

1. git clone --recursive https://github.com/sass/node-sass.git
2. cd node-sass
3. npm install
4. node scripts/build -f
5. cd ..
6. npm install node-sass --sass-binary-path=C:\Users<you-path>\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-93\binding.node

That seemed to work for me. But then after all that effort, v.4.14.1 was incompatible with another package so I was ready to flip a table by that point < insert-table-flipping-meme >.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30909298)