# `npm i core-js@latest` won't install because it can't build... core-js@<3.3?

Tags: npm, core-js

I'm trying to revive the build for [an old, unmaintained library](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect) so that we can check in some changes (or publish a fork) that lets it play nicely with another updated library (namely Bootstrap 4, but that's not important for this question).

When trying a vanilla `npm i`, well, first I got some places where the library's package.json conflicted with its dependencies' dependencies because of `~` vs `^` conflicts -- the dependencies were more lenient about versions, so I changed a few dependencies in the main project from `~` to `^` to match. No big deal.

*But then...* `npm i` got bogged down where it looked like something was building before it eventually gave up.

The last line to display before it seems to hang is this:

```
⸨                  ⸩ ⠴ reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/selenium-webdriver Completed in 8604ms
```

It then calls `clang` and `make` over and over for a while (on macOS Big Sur, and I can see the commands in the terminal's title bar), before finally re-entering `npm i` and puking all over the place.

The puke starts with:

```
npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Applications/projects/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761457/npm-cannot-install-node-sass) seems at least similar, as it has similar issues with `node-sass`, but the library doesn't have `node-sass` anywhere in the [its package.json](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/blob/master/package.json), which suggests it's a dependency of a dependency that's grabbing node-sass... so I'm not sure how to edit the node-sass dependency from where I'm at without guessing at a lot of dependency versions.

---

#### Trying to install core-js@latest

Okay, fine. Let's try to install core-js **greater than** 3.3 and see if we can force that to work somehow.

In fact, let's try getting the latest (looks like that's [3.13 atm](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/releases))...

```
npm i -D core-js@latest
```

And here's the weird thing:

> ***That gives me the same errors!***

As in literally the same stuff:

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

Huh? core-js@latest requires core-js@<3.3 to build?

What's going on here?

---

#### More logging!

I'm going to try to select stuff that looks useful from the log screed after the `npm Err!` I pasted above, in case it's useful. To be clear, this is from the first attempt at `npm i` for the [entire library](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/blob/master/package.json), and **IS NOT** for `npm install -D core-js@latest`.

```
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Applications/projects/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
```

... then some flavor of this several times:

```
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp:2:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1361:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' of type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-analysis]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerator_units())
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1361:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerator_units())
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1363:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' of type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-analysis]
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominator_units())
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1363:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominator_units())
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
```

... before rounding out with this:

```
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:3:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/sass_context_wrapper.h:9:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/custom_function_bridge.h:7:
npm ERR! ../src/callback_bridge.h:110:23: warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
npm ERR!       this->callback->Call(argv_v8.size(), &argv_v8[0])
npm ERR!                       ^
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:32:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'CallbackBridge<Sass_Value *, void *>::operator()' requested here
npm ERR!   return bridge(argv);
npm ERR!                ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:1741:3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
npm ERR!   NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:106:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
npm ERR! # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR! 6 warnings generated.
npm ERR! ../src/create_string.cpp:17:25: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'v8::String::Utf8Value'
npm ERR!   v8::String::Utf8Value string(value);
npm ERR!                         ^      ~~~~~
npm ERR! /Users/myLogin/.node-gyp/14.15.1/include/node/v8.h:3294:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Local<v8::Value>' to 'const v8::String::Utf8Value' for 1st argument
npm ERR!     Utf8Value(const Utf8Value&) = delete;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! /Users/myLogin/.node-gyp/14.15.1/include/node/v8.h:3287:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
npm ERR!     Utf8Value(Isolate* isolate, Local<v8::Value> obj);
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Applications/projects/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Applications/projects/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Applications/projects/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

I'm afraid this is above my paygrade. What's going on?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I had same problem.

Comment: @ASSASSIN1030 No luck yet. We're just not using that component for now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but in case anyone else is this command worked for me:

npm install --save core-js@^3